# why doesn't my UIImage appear in my tabBar?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbar

I'm trying to add an `UIImage` to customise my `tabBar` just like I did with my `navigationBar`, but it seems not work.

First I create a `CAGradientLayer` and then I turn it into `UIImage`. Here is the code:

```
extension CALayer {

    func createImageFromLayer() -> UIImage?{
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
        render(in: context)
        let output = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return output
    }

}

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    let grad: CAGradientLayer = {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear, UIColor.black]
        gradient.locations = [0,1]
        return gradient
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tabImage = grad.createImageFromLayer()
        self.tabBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.tabBar.backgroundImage = tabImage
        self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

Setting an image for my `navigationBar` worked perfectly using this method:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(barImg, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

In this code `barImg` is `UIImage` created from a `CAGradientLayer` just like with `tabBar`. I've checked if `tabImage` is `nil` and it's not.

It seems like `tabBar` doesn't have a function like `tabBar.setBackgroundImage` like `navigationBar`. How do I go about doing this?

The only result I get is a completely clear background for my `tabBar` with no gradient added and I don't know what I'm missing here once `tabBar.backgroundImage` doesn't work.

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

At first, when you setup colors for a `CAGradientLayer` you should use `CGColor` objects only. So you need to change that line to

```
gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
```

After that your `tabImage` won't be empty and become visible.

The last problem is that you always set your image size to `1000x1000` pixels. That's way too much. To fix that you can pass target frame size to `createImageFromLayer` as a parameter. Its signature will become something like this.

```
func createImageFromLayer(targetFrame: CGRect) -> UIImage?
```

In your case `targetFrame` is `tabBar.bounds`.